# How to replace Alt gr with Alt R?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My latin-american keyboard comes with **Alt Gr** key (**ISO_Level3_Shift**), but it is useless for my work, so I would like to replace it with **Alt R** at the lowest level possible. I've tried in xmodmap with:

```
keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = Alt_R
```

but it doesn't work (xev still reports ISO_Level3_Shift).

How can I kill for good Alt GR?

Answer (score 4):

Using the *keycode* instead of the *keysym* should work. You can also find it in the xev output. For me it's:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```