# How to make my Alt_R function as another Control on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, emacs, xorg, xmodmap

I want to use my right Alt as another Control key to use with Emacs.

I tried following (with modifications) this tutorial: http://earthviaradio.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/swapping-the-left-alt-and-ctrl-keys-in-ubuntu-11-10/

So now I have this in my .Xmodmap file:

```
clear control
keycode 108 = Control_R
add control = Control_L Control_R
```

After I restart X.org, it doesn't seem to have an effect on how keys behave. Key 108 still functions as Alt. 
But when I explore it with **xev**, I can clearly see my changes. When I press the right Alt, I get this:

```
keycode 108 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R)
```

It seems to "know" about my changes, but to not respect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found the right answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl

I'll post exactly what I have in my .Xmodmap now, as what I want is a bit different than the linked question. I don't want to unbind my right Ctrl, only to add another one (the right Alt).

```
remove Mod1 = Alt_R
keycode 108 = Control_R
add Control = Control_R
```

This is the minimal impact on the keyboard I can think of. What it does is only unbind Alt_R and bind Control_R to the same key.
This should work on any linux, not only Ubuntu, as the linked question. I tested on Ubuntu, Fedora and OpenSUSE.

Comment: This no more works as of Ubuntu 16.04. One relatively easy solution is to modify  /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev  and change the key codes for RALT and RCTL:
 <RCTL> = 108;
 <RALT> = 105;
This is probably not a "correct" solution as it changes system wide files which will probably get overwritten on package updates etc. Still haven't found a better one though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are one of the unfortunate people like me that could not get xmodmap to switch right Alt with right Ctrl, then maybe this will help.

**If you press right Alt and e and you get é then this solution is for you (needs improvement).**

Run this in the terminal (check your keycodes with xev):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```

then put this code in your .Xmodmap:

```
remove Control = Control_R
remove Mod1 = Alt_R
keycode 105 = Alt_R
keycode 108 = Control_R
add Control = Control_R
add Mod1 = Alt_R
```

This code sets your Alt_Gr key to Alt_R, and then it swaps Alt_r with Ctrl_R.

If you want this to remain after you logout, put the following commands in any of your startup shell files, for example ~/.profile:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
  xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
  /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi
```

sources: [question1](https://superuser.com/a/383243/586011) [question2](https://askubuntu.com/a/280058/390931)